# A method which given two integers returns the value that is closest to 1000

Tags: c#

I was given this coding assignment and here is what I came up with. Is there a better and a more efficient way to do this ?

```
public void GetNumberClosestToValue(int num1, int num2)
{
    int numberToCompareTo = 1000;

    try
    {
        int modNum1 = num1 % numberToCompareTo;
        int modNum2 = num2 % numberToCompareTo;

        int quotientNum1 = num1 / numberToCompareTo;
        int quotientNum2 = num2 / numberToCompareTo;

        if (num1 == num2 || Math.Abs(numberToCompareTo - num1) == Math.Abs(numberToCompareTo - num2))
            Console.WriteLine("Both numbers {0} , {1} are equally closer to {2} ", num1, num2, numberToCompareTo);
        else if (quotientNum1 == quotientNum2)
            Console.WriteLine("Number Closest to {0} is {1}", numberToCompareTo, modNum1 > modNum2 ? num1 : num2);
        else if (Math.Abs(quotientNum1) > Math.Abs(quotientNum2))
            Console.WriteLine("Number Closest to {0} is {1}", numberToCompareTo, num2);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Number Closest to {0} is {1}", numberToCompareTo, num1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just take the absolute value of the smallest of the two after doing `1000 - num1` and `1000 - num2`?

Comment: This is better suited to Code Review or Code Golf dont you think?

Comment: @SteveWellens - question shows good effort on OP part, so I don't really think it matters whether it test, homework or interview question. Maybe better for CR site... but I think ok on SO too.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what the division stuff was for. Definitely showed some effort and a novel approach though!

Comment: Sorry guys if I posted in the wrong forum, can you please give me a link to any of the code review sites ?

Comment: @user3375390 You can go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to have code reviewed. Take note however that several people did defend your question and you got some great answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
public int GetNumberClosestTo1000(int num1, int num2)
{
    return Math.Abs(1000 - num1) > Math.Abs(1000 - num2) ? num2 : num1;
}
```

This gets the distance to 1000 (using `Math.Abs` which returns the absolute value of a number and subtraction to get the relative distance) and then uses a ternary to take the results of the comparison and return the correct value.

Note that this doesn't handle the equals case all that well (it would return num1), but you can only have one return value.

Making the method generic would certainly be a better approach:

```
public int GetNumberClosestToValue(int num1, int num2, int value)
{
    return Math.Abs(value - num1) > Math.Abs(value - num2) ? num2 : num1;
}
```

Using `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue` would cause an overflow (thanks @ConradFrix for pointing this out!), and aren't handled here. The handling of these edge cases would depend on the function requirements for said edge cases. Just something to be aware of if this were production code.

Comment: This returns num1 when they are equally distant but otherwise is what I would do.

Comment: @ConradFrix, The expression would evaluate to `false` for equal, and so return num1. Otherwise yeah, I don't have a good answer for the equals case given that it is supposed to "return the value" (you obviously can't return two values without severly changing the requirements).

Comment: it says value that is closest, so per the requirements you shouldn't need to deal with it being equal so long as it returns one of them

Comment: Well the op isn't actually returning anything. Also if int.minvalue is passed in you'll overflow. The op would need to specify what should happen there

Comment: @ConradFrix I noticed the OP was printing instead of returning, but took the question title over the sample (perhaps he doesn't understand return values?). MinValue is definitely an edge case that would need defining (as is MaxValue).

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks "returns" so I'd modify the function to actually return that value.

Additionally, I'd make it modular by adding the value as a parameter.

```
public int GetNumberClosestToValue(int num1, int num2, int value)
{
    return Math.Abs(value - num1) < Math.Abs(value - num2) ? num1 : num2;
}
```

You can then simply call it as:

```
int closest = GetNumberClosestToValue(x, y, 1000);
```

Or overload it:

```
public int GetNumberClosestToValue(int num1, int num2)
{
    return GetNumberClosestToValue(num1, num2, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return the actual numbers, just the smallest distance.

Comment: Still won't work, the Math.Min will return the minimum distance which is pretty much guaranteed to not equal num1 (unless it is 0)

Comment: I've had those days. Looks good now! I like the overload idea for the "It absolutely has to look like this" problem.

Answer (score 1):

A version which will also account for equality could use something like `IComparable`'s `CompareTo`, which returns -1 for less than, 0 for equal, and +1 for greater than:

```
public int CompareAbsoluteDistanceFromValue(int num1, int num2, int value)
{
    var abs1 = Math.Abs(value-num1);
    var abs2 = Math.Abs(value-num2);
    return abs1.CompareTo(abs2);
}
```

Then you can easily `switch` on `CompareAbsoluteDistanceFromValue(num1, num2, 1000)`, with `case`s for -1, 0 and 1. Remember that -1 means num1 is closer, 1 means num2 is closer.

So completing the code, using this in your original example method would look like:

```
public void GetNumberClosestToValue(int num1, int num2)
{
    int numberToCompareTo = 1000;
    switch(CompareAbsoluteDistanceFromValue(num1, num2, numberToCompareTo))
    {
        case -1:
            Console.WriteLine("Number Closest to {0} is {1}", numberToCompareTo, num1);
            break;
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("Both numbers {0} , {1} are equally closer to {2} ", num1, num2, numberToCompareTo);
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Number Closest to {0} is {1}", numberToCompareTo, num2);
            break;
    }
}
```

There may be room to neaten that up a bit, but you get the idea.

Comment: +1 for cstring style comparison (*recalls if statements with strcompare and shudders*)